# GridGain join query with both objects returned

Tags: gridgain

Is it possible to return both objects of a join as the result of a GridGain cache query?

We can get either one of the sides of the join or fields from both (and then use these to retrieve each object separately), but looking at the examples and documentation there seems to be no way to get both objects.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@dejan- In GridGain and Apache Ignite, you can use _key and _val functionality with SqlFieldsQuery in order to return an object. For example -

```
SqlFieldsQuery sql = new SqlFieldsQuery(
 "select a._key, a._val, b._val from SomeTypeA a, SomeTypeB b " +
   "where a.id = b.otherId");

try (QueryCursor<List<?>> cursor = cache.query(sql) {
  for (List<?> row : cursor)
    System.out.println("Row: " + row);
}
```

Note that in this case the object will be returned in a Serialized form.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, GridGain Open Source edition is now [Apache Ignite](https://ignite.incubator.apache.org/), so I would recommend switching.

In Ignite, you can return exactly the fields you need from a query using [SqlFieldsQuery](http://apacheignite.readme.io/v1.0/docs/cache-queries#field-queries), like so:

```
SqlFieldsQuery sql = new SqlFieldsQuery(
  "select fieldA1, fieldA2, fieldB3 from SomeTypeA a, SomeTypeB b " +
    "where a.id = b.otherId");

try (QueryCursor<List<?>> cursor = cache.query(sql) {
  for (List<?> row : cursor)
    System.out.println("Row: " + row);
}
```

In GridGain open source edtion, you can use GridGain fields query APIs as well.

Comment: Thanks Dmitriy. We will switch to Apache Ignite, however it would take us a week or two and we'd like to complete this before the switch. As I already mentioned, the fields query would work, but ideally we would get the objects on both sides rather than a collection of fields.